# Wed Apr 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), how to get a time using mat date picker in angular

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using mat date picker in the form to show the date, it is working fine when I show the form. I need to show the created date and time, but the output coming like this:
Wed Apr 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). How to display the time?

```
 this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
 createAt: [],
})
```

html

```
       <mat-card-subtitle><b> Created At : </b> {{ firstFormGroup.controls['createAt'].value | date:'short'}}</mat-card-subtitle> 
   <!-- Date -->
              <div class="row">
                <b class="dateLabel">Date:</b>
                <mat-form-field class="date" (click)="createAt.open()">
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="createAt" autocomplete="off" formControlName="createAt" placeholder="Date"
                    [value]="createAt" > 
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="createAt"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #createAt></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>        
            </div>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. The date picker only selects a date, as it should. Do you want to additionally select a time, or do you want to write the current time into the object?

Comment: @kacase i need to show the time also along with the date

Comment: mat-datepicker doesnt allow showing time. Either you add an additional form-field or create a custom component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using mat datepicker we cannot able to show time, but if we want to show the created time , we use the below code
using moment

```
moment().format()
```

it displays the current time and date. 
and also we can use the predefined datepipe